# Xamarin Async method usage OnStart()

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await

Is it considered a good practice to call an `Async` method that does some heavy lifting with server connections and data exchange during `OnStart()` event of the application given that this method does not touch the UI thread? Are all the components of the application properly initialized at the time of this event firing for the `Async` method to be able to execute?

```
protected override async void OnStart()
{
    sendHttpRequestAsync();
}

private async void sendHttpRequestAsync() {
  await ...
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avoid using `async void` on anything except event handlers.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

[`OnStart`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Application.OnStart()/) however is not an event handler. Just a regular method that according to documentation...

> Application developers override this method to perform actions when the application starts.

As a work around you can create your own custom event and handler that will allow for an `async void` to be performed on your event handler. You will subscribe to the event when `OnStart` is invoked by the application and then raise the custom event to be handled asynchronously. `sendHttpRequestAsync()` would need to be refactored to return a `Task` so that it can be awaited safely.

```
//Custom event that is raised when the application is starting
private event EventHandler Starting = delegate { };

//Application developers override this method  
//to perform actions when the application starts.
protected override void OnStart() {
    //subscribe to event
    Starting += onStarting;
    //raise event
    Starting(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

private async void onStarting(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    //unsubscribe from event
    Starting -= onStarting;
    //perform non-blocking actions
    await sendHttpRequestAsync();
}

private async Task sendHttpRequestAsync() {
    await ...
}
```

Comment: Does this code actually run an differently from using `async void OnStart()` ?

Comment: Yes. I would suggest you review the included link in the question about async  best practices.

Comment: How is this different than making OnStart async void?  In both cases the result of the task is silently ignored.

Comment: Here is a complete article on this topic : https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-async-task-startup/

Comment: @kapusch Be aware of this article and also this [one](https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-call-this-async-method-in-my-xamarin-forms-when-my-app-starts). The `OnStart()` it's not an event handler, as the answer actually says very clear on the second sentence, so it's not ok to use `async void OnStart` as the writer of the post you linked suggests.

Comment: Oh I very much dislike that this is the accepted answer, and I realise that Xamarin is on the way out, but a few things:

1) OnStart is on a different thread (at least for Android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation#onStart()) so blocking calls are ok - firing an event seems excessive.

2) Async void is generally still ok, despite the best practices (just handle exceptions with a try catch) so don't discount it as an option.

3) But better: consider a TaskCompletionSource in a blocking call.