# How do I to execute a function on background in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to execute a function on background when my app will open, to do this, I am trying to create an async function with task but I cannot do it works.

How do I to fix it ?

**Xamarin OnStart**

```
protected override void OnStart(){
     DefineConcursoSession();
}

//execute in background
private async void DefineConcursoSession(){
        ConcursoDTO dto = await ConcursoService.GetConcursoAtivo();
        //save session
    }
```

**HttpClient**

```
public async static Task<ConcursoDTO> GetConcursoAtivo(){
        String ENDPOINT = "/GetConcursoAtivo";
        String URL_FINAL = URL_CONTROLLER + ENDPOINT;

        ConcursoDTO dto = new ConcursoDTO();

        try
        {
            HttpClient hClient = new HttpClient();
            hClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            hClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", BasicAuth.getHash());

            //get
            HttpResponseMessage response = hClient.GetAsync(URL_FINAL).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            var resultContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            //Console.WriteLine("Content: " + resultContent);


            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){                
                JObject jo = JObject.Parse(resultContent);
                dto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConcursoDTO>(jo["Concurso"].ToString());                
                
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Erro: GetConcursoAtivo:-> " + e.Message);
        }

        return dto;

    }
```

Comment: Think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957339/xamarin-async-method-usage-onstart

Comment: Hi, iOS and Android have their own background technologies to achieve that, you could have a look at [iOS Backgrounding with Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/ios-backgrounding-techniques/ios-backgrounding-with-tasks)  and [Android Services in Remote Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/out-of-process-services).