# Why awaiting in App.OnStart() before setting the MainPage property doesn't load main page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

First of all, I know the documentation states that I should set the `MainPage` property in the `App` class constructor (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class#mainpage-property).

To simplify, what I need to do is some async operation in the OnStart() event handler and after that, set the MainPage property. This question wants to get to the root issue in the framework itself.

Something like this (simplified on a blank Xamarin.Forms project, you can try if you want):

```
public partial class App : Application
{

    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        //Uncomenting the following line makes the page be shown
        //MainPage = new Page() { BackgroundColor = Color.Red };
        
        //Simulate some fast async work. If you comment this line the MainPage will be shown just fine
        await Task.Delay(100);

        //The page is never displayed to the user unless first commented line in this method is uncommented
        MainPage = new Page(){ BackgroundColor = Color.Red };
    }
}
```

If you just don't await anything and do all code synchronous, the MainPage is set properly, but not if I await any task. Why?

As the `await Task.Delay(100)`call returns to the original SynchronizationContext (I assume will be on the UI thread), I don't think this is the issue.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see, `OnStart` returns void, not `Task`, so it's not intended to be asynchronous. You made it `async void` but caller (framework code which calls OnStart) has no means to wait for that async operation to complete. For caller, `OnStart` completes right when `await Task.Delay` hits (that's when `OnStart` returns), and so it continues to other stuff. When `await Task.Delay` completes and you set `MainPage` - you are not actually in `OnStart` stage of initialization process, that stage has already been completed 100 milliseconds ago.

Consider this example which should clarify it:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var app = new Application();
        app.Start();
    }
}

class Application
{
    public string MainPage { get; set; }
    protected virtual void OnStart()
    {

    }

    public void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("calling OnStart");
        // can't await or anything here, it returns void
        OnStart();

        Console.WriteLine("OnStart called");
        // now we consider initialization is done and check MainPage
        if (MainPage != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MainPage);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Initialization done");
    }
}

class MyApplication : Application
{
    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        // we set MainPage but it's too late
        MainPage = "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand now the issue, thanks for the clarification. As some [others](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-async-task-startup/) I believed (wrongly) that the OnStart() was an event handler... The `override` keyword should have warned me about that. 
What would you suggest, then, to perform async work on app start? Some of these solutions that Stephen [suggests](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html)? Or maybe this other [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957339/xamarin-async-method-usage-onstart) would be better?

Comment: Second link doesn't do anything useful, it's the same as what you already do now. Event handlers are not special so creating event, subscribing to it and raising it doesn't change anything. Your problem is not async void by itself but the fact that framework needs main page to display to the user, so you need to provide one and _then_ perform your async operation (maybe even showing the progress on that page).

Comment: If you must perform this async operation in OnStart - then async void is acceptable for the same reason it's acceptable on event handlers - you have no choice (OnStart returns void and you can't change it). When you happen in situation where you have to use async void - always wrap the whole thing into try catch block and handle exceptions accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for you fast answers. Then, I guess it's ok to treat the OnStart as an event but knowing that you shouldn't expect it to set your MainPage or do anything related to it without having already one MainPage set before. It's kind of misleading somehow in my opinion, but once you know, you are fine.

Comment: You might also move your async operation into separate method (`private Task MyAsyncStuff()`) and then in `OnStart` do `MyAsyncStuff().ContinueWith(x => ... error handling here ...)`. Then your `OnStart` will not be async void, and it will be not misleading. You will clearly be starting completely separate async operation, independent of OnStart method itself.

Comment: I'll investigate your proposal thanks.  I'm worried about not having the benefits of using async/await though.

Comment: Well your `MyAsyncStuff()` will be async itself (`private async Task MyAsyncStuff()`), so there benefits are still there. You just move the logic outside of OnStartup and not make OnStartup async to remove confusion. Now you have synchronous OnStartup during which you start separate asynchronous work, which will complete independent of OnStartup. So it's the same as you have now, but intention is much more clear.